# \Beamergotobutton's color

Tags: beamer, hyperref

Is there any way to change the default \beamergotobuttoncolor ?

I've changed many things in my presentation's theme and now that I'm at the end I've discovered that with these settings it is impossible to see the button created by the beamergotobutton command. I'd like to change only the color of the button without any modification of the theme of other things.

My buttons are all in the appendix and the exact command I use to generate them is the following:

```
\hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{Appendice}}
```

In the preambol I have the following definition:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}                  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=mycolor}
```

Thank you in advance!

As asked by @Claudio Fiandrino this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}                  
\definecolor{sapienza}{HTML}{98002E}        
\definecolor{royalblue}{RGB}{176,196,222}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[italian]{babel}        

\usepackage{hyperref}                  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=sapienza}



\mode<beamer>  %COMPLETE configuration of my beamer mode
{
\usefonttheme[stillsansseriftext]{serif}          

\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black, fg=royalblue}   
\usetheme{PaloAlto}         

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]         

\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{%                  
family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}    

\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=royalblue,fg=sapienza}         

\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=sapienza}    

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}         

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=sapienza}           

\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=sapienza}    
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=blue}

\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg= sapienza} 


\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]         

\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}

}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Appendice}
\label{appendix}

\hyperlink{distr-c1-c1}{\beamergotobutton{La distribuzione C1-C1}}

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}{La distribuzione C1-C1}
\label{distr-c1-c1}

some text

\hyperlink{appendix}{\beamergotobutton{Appendice}}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably your MWE could have been more M and less WE ;-) Thanks for following up with an answer +1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got it!!! Reading the suggestion from here:

http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12180

after many trial and errors I find the correct line to change the button's color:

```
\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=black,fg=yellow}
```