# Different colors for beamergotobutton and beamerreturnbutton?

Tags: beamer, color, return, button

In [This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63171/beamergotobuttons-color), @luigi_tiburzi shows how to change the color of a beamer button, i.e.,

```
\setbeamercolor{button}{fg=black,bg=red}
```

Unfortunately it changes both the `goto` and `return` buttons

I tried the obvious thing:

```
\setbeamercolor{beamerreturnbutton}{fg=black,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{beamergotobutton}{fg=black,bg=blue}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different buttons don't have individual colors, so just `\setbeamercolor` won't work.

But you can redefine one of the button commands and set the colors therein.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{button}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\renewcommand{\beamerreturnbutton}[1]{%
    \begingroup% keep color changes local
    \setbeamercolor{button}{fg=black,bg=red}%
    \beamerbutton{\insertreturnsymbol#1}% original definition
    \endgroup
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Colorful Buttons}
\beamergotobutton{Goto 1}

\beamerreturnbutton{Return}

\beamergotobutton{Goto 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]